# Understanding ThreadPoolExecutor internal working

Tags: java, threadpoolexecutor

I am having following code:

```
public class ExecFramework implements Runnable {
int i;

public ExecFramework() {

}

public ExecFramework(int i) {
    this.i = i;
}

public void run() {
    System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " " + i);
    try {
        Thread.sleep(10);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    ExecutorService pool=new ThreadPoolExecutor(2, 10, 5000,TimeUnit.SECONDS, new ArrayBlockingQueue(2));
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
        Runnable obj=new ExecFramework(i);
        pool.execute(obj);
    }
    pool.shutdown();
    while(pool.isTerminated()){
        System.out.println("ExecutorService is terminated");
    }

}
```

}

Is my knowledge for the way ThreadPoolExecutor works correct:

> 1. If NumberOfThreadRunning < CoreNumberOfThreads then ThreadPoolExecutor creates a new thread to complete the task.
> 2. If NumberOfThreadRunning > CoreNumberOfThreads then queue this task in BlockingQueue but if queue is full then create a new Thread only if
>      NumberOfThread < MaxNumberOfThreads.
> 3. Once the task is completed thread running that task is available for other task.

According to 3rd point. I should be able to execute 20 tasks using ThreadPoolExecutor.

Why Output of above code is?

```html
pool-1-thread-5 6
pool-1-thread-4 5
pool-1-thread-3 4
pool-1-thread-1 0
pool-1-thread-2 1
pool-1-thread-6 7
pool-1-thread-7 8
pool-1-thread-8 9
pool-1-thread-9 10
pool-1-thread-10 11
Exception in thread "main" java.util.concurrent.RejectedExecutionException: Task executionFramework.ExecFramework@232204a1 rejected from java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor@4aa298b7[Running, pool size = 10, active threads = 10, queued tasks = 2, completed tasks = 0]
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$AbortPolicy.rejectedExecution(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:2063)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.reject(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:830)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.execute(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1379)
 at executionFramework.ExecFramework.main(ExecFramework.java:88)
pool-1-thread-8 2
pool-1-thread-6 3
```

Answer (score 0):

The documentation says it: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html

In section **Rejected tasks**.

In your case i would guess this :

> when the Executor uses finite bounds for both maximum threads and work queue capacity, and is saturated

happens.

Comment: Is my understanding about the ThreadPoolExecutor correct? 3 points which I have given in my question

Comment: Whenever we call execute on ThreadPoolExecutor does it always creates a new Thread in ThreadPoolExecutor?

Comment: No a ThreadPoll creates Threads on needs till the defined maximum. When you give a working-queue, as you do, and this queue ist saturated an no thread is available, than this happens. Try to not provide this working queue or just make it bigger. The working queue holds the runables till they are posted to the executors. In your case the Threads in the executor are busy and the queue of holding the runnables to be forwarded to the pool is also full